# Can't link node -- "No such keg exists"

Tags: xcode, macos, node.js, terminal

So I've been trying to get node installed all day. I've reinstalled Xcode, installed command line tools, brew prune, brew cleanup, deleted node, reinstalled again, and it still will not link. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Running OSX 10.8.2

```
acd41302428433:Cellar rrichrs$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.8.15... Warning: Could not link node. Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.8.15/bin/npm
Target /usr/local/bin/npm already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and delete this file, do:
brew link --overwrite formula_name

To list all files that would be deleted:
brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
acd41302428433:Cellar rrichrs$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/formula_name
acd41302428433:Cellar rrichrs$
```

Comment: what's wrong with using the official node installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this doesn't answer your question exactly. But I highly recommend installing nvm for node. This will let you run several versions of node and change between them. Node changes so fast, and I've ran into projects where an older version of node was required. With nvm it's as easy as

```
nvm install 0.4.2
nvm use 0.4.2
```

[Documentation and install instructions for nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

basically installing is as simple as copying and pasting a curl command into the terminal:

```
curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: I assume this is the same idea as rvm? I'll give it a try, Thanks!